# Please help me parse the subject complement of

Tags: syntax-trees, parsing

The 2 questions are on the diagram.
In question 1 - I emphasize "function as" because my understanding is that (in English) a predicate nominative - even though it can take the form of a preposition or even a adverb - must ultimately function either as an adjective or a noun.

In addition - a question 3) Does the verb "BE" always act as a linking/copula (i.e. does it always introduce a subject complement?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since *the one* has an article, it seems fair to treat it like a (pro)noun, so it functions as a noun subject complement.

*For whom you are looking* is as a whole a relative clause modifying *the one*, so I would make it one branch from the "predicate nominative" down, so the two branches would be *the one* and *for whom you are looking*.

Then I would probably branch off *whom* (the relative pronoun) on the one hand and *you are looking for [zero]* on the other; but there is something to be said for doing *for whom* v. *you are looking*. The problem is that *whom* is both the object of the preposition *for* and the node that introduces the relative clause.

This below website uses a "silent complementiser *that*" for my [zero], which seems contrived (the word *that* is not possible in that sentence), but do with it what you will. It seems clear that you need to add a node for this [zero], whatever you call it. Perhaps look into *wh-movement* for English. An example of how they parse relative clauses:

[image]

http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/ch11.html, figure 39b.

Comment: Yes, there are several unnecessary presuppositions encoded in this tree. But although it's mislabelled and overdecorated, it gets the constituents right (with a different sentence, without pied piping; I wonder what the tree for _the people with whom you talked_) would be.

Comment: The answer mostly provides what the question is looking for. But there are indeed a number of presuppositions in the tree that can be challenged. For instance, the tree assumes DPs, as opposed to NPs. The tree assumes a null "that", as mentioned in the answer. The tree assumes strict binarity of branching. And most importantly in my view, the tree assumes the presence of a finite VP constituent. All of these presuppositions can be challenged.